# Continuous projective geometry on the interval

Tags: gn.general-topology, projective-geometry

Put $P=[0,1]$. Is there a compact subset $L$ of the hyper space of $P$ such that the pair $(P, L)$ satisfies  the following axioms of projective geometry. Furthermore  the obvious maps from the configuration space of $P$ to $L$ and configuration space of $L$ to $P$ would be continuous?

[Non-isomorphic projective planes on $\omega$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261436/non-isomorphic-projective-planes-on-omega)

Comment: I like this question while I still do not follow the second part, about *configuration spaces* and about the *natural* mappings. I am not even sure about the definition of the *hyperspace* (Different papers apply different definitions which are not equivalent).

Comment: I am quite sure that the hyperspace is defined as the space of compact subsets (possibly non-empty compact subsets) with the Hausdorff metric. (?) Then my guess would be *no* if line $\ p(a\ b)\ $ depends continuously on $\ \{a\ b\}\ $ for $\ a\ne b$.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński     Thank you  for  your  comments  on my  question. By  Hyperspace  of  $P$,, as  you  pointed out, I mean the space  of  all  non empty  compact  subsets  of  $P$  which is  a  compact  space  with  Hausdorff  metric. The  obvious  map sends the  pair  $(a,b)\in P\times P\;\;\;   a\neq b$, the  configuration space,  to the  unique  line $l(a,b)$.

Comment: (To do LaTeX on MO is hard :) ).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński  You  are  well  come.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński  Yes  Latex  is  hard  in MO :)).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński  May  I  ask  you to  mention the  motivation for  your  guess that the  answer  would  be  no?

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński  Dear  Prof. Holsztynski  My  apology I  did  not  recognized you. I  have  deep  admiration to you. I have admiration also to  the mathematical heritage  of  Prof. Borsuk.  Thanks  again for  your  attention to my  question.

Comment: Ali, your question was clear, it was only me who had a temporary difficulty.

My feeling about the YES/NO was naive. I simply tried somehow to imagine things and shared my early vague intuition. I plan to think more about this question.

You may ask about the class of all projective plane topological spaces (meaning the spaces as you have described it without assuming that they are an interval). This may give a general insight into this topic.

Comment: Your question is truly topological. A less stylistic version, possibly harder, would be omitting the continuity of the natural mappings (but let the "projective lines" be compact).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(P,L)$ is an abstract projective plane, then for any point $p\in P$ and any line $\ell\in L$ not incident to $p$ there is a bijection between the set of points incident to $\ell$ and the set of lines incident to $p$. Under a reasonable definition of "topological projective plane" this bijection should be a homeomorphism.

If $P=[0,1]$, then the space of all lines incident to $0$ has a continuous surjection from the connected space $(0,1]$. It follows that for each line $\ell$ the space of all points incident to $\ell$ is connected. But one of these lines has both $0$ and $1$ in it, and the only connected subset of an interval containing both endpoints is the whole interval. Contradiction.

Comment: Prof. GoodWillie  thank you  very  much  for  your  interesting answer. I  am thinking  to replacement of  other spaces by the  interval  for  example  circle, spheres,.etc.

Comment: It's rather clear that the topological projective planes should be topologically homogenous. In the compact case they cannot be 1-dimensional.

Comment: Assuming these are Hausdorff spaces, the plane must be locally homeomorphic to the product of two of its lines, so it seems that it must be even-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

As a useful (I hope) step toward solving Ali Taghavi's problem, let me propose the following general definition of a topological projective plane:

**DEFINITION**   A topological projective plane is an ordered quadruple $\ \mathbf P\ :=\ (\,P\ L\ \vee \wedge\,)\ $ such that $\ P\ $ and $\ L\ $ are topological spaces, and $\ \vee:\binom P2\rightarrow L\ $ and
$\ \wedge:\binom L2\rightarrow P\ $ are continuous functions,
and $\ \mathbf P\ $ is a projective plane in the usual (non-topological, just abstract) sense, i.e. the following axioms hold:

1. $\ \forall_{\{a\ b\ c\}\in\binom P3}\ 
              (\,a\vee b = b\vee c\ \Rightarrow\ a\vee c=a\vee b\,) $
2. $\ \forall_{\{A\ B\ C\}\in\binom L3}\ 
            (\,A\wedge B = B\wedge C\ \Rightarrow\ A\wedge C = A\wedge B\,) $
3. $\ \forall_{\{A\ B\ C\}\in\binom L3}\ \left( A\wedge B=A\wedge C\quad or \quad (A\wedge B)\vee(A\wedge C) = A \right) $
4. $\ \forall_{\{a\ b\ c\}\in\binom P3}\ \left(a\vee b=a\vee c\quad
        or  \quad (a\vee b)\wedge(a\vee c) = a \right) $
5. $\ \exists_{E\in\binom P4}\  
       \left|\left\{x\vee y: \{x\ y\}\in\binom E2\right\}\right| = \binom 42 $

> **REMARK**   Axioms 1 and 2 can be written in the style of axioms 2 and 3 as follows:

> 1'. $\ \forall_{T\in\binom P3}\ 
>         \left|\left\{x\vee y: \{x\ y\}\in\binom T2\right\}\right| \ =\ 1\ \text{or}\ \ 3  $

> 2'. $\ \forall_{t\in\binom L3}\ 
>         \left|\left\{X\wedge Y: \{X\ Y\}\in\binom t2\right\}\right|\ =\ 1\ \text{or}\ 3  $

Now one can impose additional constraints, perhaps topological, on the notion of the topological projective plane to obtain more specialized (narrower) classes.

> **Acknowledgment**    The definition here is a simplification and generalization of the definition given by Ali Taghavi from the ***Question*** above.

---

**ADDITIONAL DEFINITIONS**

Now we may define the induced linear sets and pencils

$$ \forall_{A\in L}\ \ _\{A_\}\ :=\ \bigcup \vee^{-1}(A)\ =\ \bigcup
     \left\{ \{a\ b\}\in \binom P2: a\vee b = A \right\} $$
and
$$ \forall_{a\in P}\ \ ^\{p^\}\ :=\ \bigcup \wedge^{-1}(a)\ =\ \bigcup 
     \left\{ \{A\ B\}\in \binom L2: A\wedge B = a \right\} $$

---

The (default) topology in $\ \binom X2\ $ is induced by the canonical
map $\ X\times X\setminus\{(x\ x):x\in X\}\rightarrow\binom X2\ $ given by $\ (x\ y)\mapsto\{x\ y\},\ $ where $\ X\ $ is $\ P\ $ or $\ L$.

Comment: Ali, thank you for correcting my typos--I even similarly replaced the LaTeX \vee by \wedge in axiom 2'.